# How to declare a paramater with default value (previous date) in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to set default params in a stored procedure as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rpt].[STAT05] --@StartDate = '2017-08-15', @EndDate = '2017-08-16'

    @StartDate      DATETIME2 = DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) 
    ,@EndDate       DATETIME2 = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 

AS
BEGIN
```

,which however returns:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

What's wrong with that statement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129508/how-do-you-initialize-a-variable-in-a-stored-procedure-with-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value for parameters in sp have to be constants.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rpt].[STAT05] 
    @StartDate      DATETIME2 =  null 
   ,@EndDate       DATETIME2   =null
AS
BEGIN

IF @StartDate is null
SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) 

IF @EndDate is null
SET @EndDate =  DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```